# How to erase a shape drawn in an image?

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, draw

I've an image and when i click with the left button, it draws a `Rectangle`. I put on a `LinkedList` every drawn shape, so I can erase then when i want (actually when i right click the mouse button). When the method `paint()` or `repaint()` is called, it should include or remove a shape. Including is fine, but not removing :(.

Here is a short runnable of the problem

```
package classes;

import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import views.ImagePanel;

/**
 *
 * @author Luis
 */
public class Test extends JFrame{

    private ImagePanel imgPanel;

    public Test() throws HeadlessException {

        imgPanel = new ImagePanel();
        imgPanel.addMouseListener(imgPanel);
        imgPanel.addMouseWheelListener(imgPanel);

        setTitle("Test frame");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500, 500);

        add(imgPanel);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

And ImagePanel `class`

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

/**
 *
 * @author Luis
 */
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener,MouseWheelListener{

    private BufferedImage imagem = null; 

    private double txi=0;   //Series of variables to do some transformations
    private double tyi=0;   //
    private double txf=0;   //
    private double tyf=0;   //

    private double final_translx=0; //
    private double final_transly=0; //

    private double zoomFactor = 1;  //

    private LinkedList<Shape> shapes; //List of all shapes added

    private boolean zoomer = false; //

    public ImagePanel() {
        //Initializing the list and doing some config.
        shapes = new LinkedList<>();

        setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK,1));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.MOVE_CURSOR));
        try {
            //This image has 981x651, but you can replace by any other
            imagem = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/sources/image.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.

        //Doing the transformations of the jPanel inside the jFrame (possibly)
        Graphics2D panelGraphics = (Graphics2D) g;

        AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(zoomFactor, zoomFactor);
        panelGraphics.drawImage(imagem, at, this);

        //Adding shapes in the image
        Graphics2D imageGraphics = (Graphics2D)imagem.getGraphics();

        imageGraphics.setColor(Color.red);
        for (Shape s : shapes){
            //This is where i think it should overwrite all the shapes
            imageGraphics.draw(s);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if(SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)){    
            //creating a new shape when i left click the mouse
            shapes.add(new Rectangle(Math.toIntExact((long) (e.getX()/zoomFactor-final_translx)),Math.toIntExact((long) (e.getY()/zoomFactor-final_transly)), 100, 100));
        }
        else{
            if(shapes.size()>0){
                //the part when it should remove;
                shapes.removeLast();
            }
        }
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        //Initial point to calculate the translation
        if(SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)){
            txi = e.getX()/zoomFactor;
            tyi = e.getY()/zoomFactor; 
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        if(SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)){
            txf = e.getX()/zoomFactor;
            tyf = e.getY()/zoomFactor;
            final_translx += txf-txi;
            final_transly += tyf-tyi;
            //final translation
            repaint();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        //do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        //do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
        zoomer=true;
        zoomFactor += e.getWheelRotation()*0.01;
        repaint();
    }
}
```

The final purpose of this is, in the future, to add balloons and insert information in regions that the user want!
Any ideas about how to properly remove those shapes?
I'm open to any other suggestion too!

thanks in advance

Comment: if you draw on the image thats it! it stays there for ever - you need to write to the actual g of the panel

Comment: Repaint and paint only what you want left. Also do not override `paint` but `paintComponenet`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to repaint (load) the original image, draw all shapes again and omit the shape you want to remove.

Comment: Yeah, now I understand. It is working fine now, but every time I repaint, I've to load the image from the file. At a longer term, it might be not the best way... Thanks all those who helped me!